# How to have only the key with no value or how to put distinct values or into IndexedDb?

Tags: javascript, key, indexeddb

I need to put strings into IndexedDb that are **distinct**. I can have them as the key with no value (pretty new to indexedDb so don't even know if that's possible). The problem right now is that every time these strings are read they are put into IndexDb repeatedly. Don't want to write another method that would check if these values already exist, to maintain method reusability. I believe there should be a way to rewrite `upgradeDb.createObjectStore('categories', { autoIncrement: true });` to do this, just can't find how. My code:

Creating the database with the table:

```
function idbOpen() {
    return idb.open('greedy', 1, upgradeDb => {
        upgradeDb.createObjectStore('categories', { autoIncrement: true });
    });
}
```

Writing to database:

```
putArrayToDb = (tableName, arrayToPut) => {
    if (this.dbPromise) {
        this.dbPromise.then(db => {
            if (!db) return;

            var tx = db.transaction(tableName, 'readwrite');
            var store = tx.objectStore(tableName);
            arrayToPut.map(arrayItem => {
                store.put(arrayItem);
            });
        })
    }
}

putArrayToDb('categories', ["value1", "value2", "value3"]);
```

[image: database gets filled with values every refresh]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use the strings as the keys, `autoIncrement` is not what you want - it generates keys for you.

Remove the `autoIncrement` option when defining the object store, and simply put with explicit keys and a dummy value (e.g. `true`):

```
var DUMMY_VALUE = true;

arrayToPut.map(arrayItem => {
    store.put(/*value=*/DUMMY_VALUE, /*key=*/arrayItem);
});
```